# TypeError: channel.send is not a function (Deprecated?)

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im trying to build a discord bot but I need to send a message to a specific channel. I've given it 100 tries but keep getting:

`TypeError: bot.channels.fetch(...).send is not a function.`

Everywhere I read, I see "use channel.send()" but I cannot find an actual fix for my problem. Is channel.send() deprecated? Heres the line that the error throws an error on:

`bot.channels.fetch(id).send(message);`

I know channels.get() was depricated and when using .fetch(id), I get the channel object however it wont let me send the message. ANY help will be appreciated as I have spent days on this alone.
Thanks.

Full block of code:

```
var reportEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setColor('#0099ff')
   .setTitle('New Report')
   .setAuthor(msg.author.tag)
   .setDescription(reportMessage)
   .setTimestamp();
console.log(bot.channels.fetch('my channel id'));
bot.channels.fetch('my channel id').then(channel => {
   channel.send(reportEmbed);
});
```

When console logged, I get the correct channel object.

Comment: please show even more of your code. which event function is that block of code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```js
bot.channels.cache.get(id).send(message)
```

Instead

Comment: Just tried it. I got "TypeError: channel.send is not a function".

Comment: This was the line that I ran:
`bot.channels.cache.get('my channel id').send(reportEmbed);`
where "report embed is a Discord.MessageEmbed Object.

Comment: Well that line doesn't include a `channel.send()` function, so I think it's pointing to another line.

Comment: I'm stupid. It threw a similar error with the same line of code but I didnt realise. I fixed that second error and it works now. Thank you so much! I was always told .get() in general was depricated but eh. Thanks dude! :)

Comment: `bot.channels.get()` is deprecated, I think that's why you were confused. `discord.js` v12+ uses `Managers`, and thus needs the cache property now (`bot.channels.cache.get`)

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in the documentation, the fetch() method returns a promise. ([Link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch))

So, in order to get the channel, you need to use the current code:

```js
bot.channels.fetch("id").then(channel => {
  channel.send(message);
});
```

Comment: I believe I tried that already but thought I'd give it another go. The error code changed to:

```TypeError: channel.send is not a function```

Comment: It perfectly works on my side. Try to update your discord.js version to the latest.

Comment: Literally used the npm install command for the discord.js module less than 12 hours ago. Unless I’m supposed to manually change it, then it should be the most recent update right?

Comment: Normally yeah. I don’t understand why it doesn’t work so since it’s working on my side.

Comment: it is possible that it did not find a channel by that id. it might help if you put more of your code in some paste bin so that we can look at it

Comment: does the bot have access to that specific channel? like is it in the server?

Comment: Absolutely the bot has access to it. But if the bot doesn't have access, a different error is showed

Comment: hmm, can you try removing the "async" keyword?

Comment: Edited the code to have a larger block of the code. When console logged, it shows all the data for the channel. Mine (the one that doesnt work) doesn't have the async. I tried adding it, made no difference. Whats the "const config = require("./config.json");". I dont have that. Is that something you added specifically?